# Keep history of field changes from another collection in a new collection in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, php-mongodb

here's my problem:

I have a collection with ~900k entries, it's about 6Gb,this will be updated daily, at least for a while. By updated I mean, dumped and imported from a json file, which we'll get every day (this may be just temp solution).

The problem that I'm dealing with at the moment is keeping a history on 4,5 fields in a separate collection, that will be updated before/after each "update" of the main collection.

What I did, was to get all the records and loop through the results updating history collection for each entry, but running ~900k update queries is time/resource consuming and I don't think is a good practice.

The structure that I have in mind is something like this:

```
{unique_id: 'unique value from main collection', 
 history: [
           {field1: value1, 
            field2: value2, 
            field3: 'value3', 
            date_updated: '2013-12-03'
           },
           {...}
          ]
}
```

I tried mapreduce too, with output to collection, which was a lot faster, the problem with mapreduce is that I can't really keep the history because none of the options for "action" param doesn't do what I need, each time it runs, it overwrites the entries, what I need it to do is something like an upsert.

If anyone has some ideas about how can I do this I'll gladly put them to test, I ran out of ideas, and I'm not a guru in mongodb either.

I think the import / update solution is not good either, I'm looking for a solution to that too, but first to get the history done.

Comment: Is CouchDB a viable option? You will get this one for free

Comment: No, it's not, the app is using only mongodb.

Comment: @orid - Couchdb wouldn't make this any easier.

Comment: If you're trying to store the delta every day, you would need to brute force load and compare each document. Load, compare, save new, save history. Repeat. MongoDb won't be particularly good for this if you care about maximal performance. But, it's going to be slow on any database if you need to do a full table/collection scan like you describe.

Comment: I don't need to do delta, I just need to store those 4 fields in history collection, each day.